# In framelayout, if I want to put a view in the position that starts from 1/2 of the screen width

Tags: android

In framelayout, if I want to put a view in the position that starts from 1/2 of the screen width. How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that in multiple ways. It only depends if you really need to stick with the FrameLayout.

Two easiest would be those:

- FrameLayout - you would need to know whats the width of the layout (so if your layout is wrap_content it **might** get tricky). Set your view's *gravity* to *left*, and set its *margin_left* to half of the layout's width.
- LinearLayout - either put it inside your FrameLayout (not very good practice), or (if you can) swap it with your FrameLayout. Set it's orientation to horizontal, add dummy view with *width = 0dp*, *weight = 1*. Then add your view with the same values for *width* and *weight*.

Comment: For the first method. I mean "1/2 of the screen width". Why it relates to height? Is there a thing relates to "half width"? Please educate me. Thanks.

Comment: oh sorry, yea I thought you meant half of the height... I edited my answer